# Cosa vuol dire “te possino”?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Ho sentito in alcune canzoni italiane e da italiani miei amici l’espressione “te possino”.

**Q: Cosa vuol dire “te possino”? È una forma regionale?**

Comment: Solo una piccola aggiunta, perché non mi sembra che sia stato menzionato nelle risposte: letteralmente “te possino” è la forma romana di “ti possano” (dove “possano” è la terza persona plurale del congiuntivo presente di “potere”), ed è sottinteso un altro verbo (spesso “ammazzare”). Poi, come correttamente spiegato, l'uso è raramente letterale, ed è spesso anzi un'espressione di meraviglia, apprezzamento o finto rimprovero.

Answer (score 1):

*Te possino* è un’espressione tipica del dialetto romano.

Si può leggere in questo [blog di dialetto romanesco](http://roma.andreapollett.com/S8/romaespr.htm) un’esauriente spiegazione:

> **te pòssin'ammazzà! 
> te pòssin'ammazzàtte! 
>  che tte pòssino!**
>
> Tipica espressione che, nonostante corrisponda a "possa tu (egli,
> ella, ecc.) essere ucciso", **nasconde dietro questo augurio in
> apparenza truce un significato assolutamente innocuo**. La congiunzione
> enfatica "che" è spesso usata per introdurre l'espressione: "Che tte
> pòssin'ammazzà!". Altrettanto spesso, il pronome relativo usato
> all'inizio dell'espressione viene ripetuto come suffisso pronominale
> -te, -lo, ecc. dopo il verbo, per dare un'enfasi ancora maggiore: te pòssin'ammazzàtte, lo pòssin'ammazzàllo, ve pòssin'ammazzàvve, e così
> via. **Di solito è usato con un senso di rimprovero, sia duro che
> blando**: ad es. nel chiamare il proprio figlio discolo una madre
> direbbe: viè quà, te pòssin'ammazzàtte! (nel senso di "vieni qua,
> furfante!"). Ma **talora è anche usato come pura esclamazione, priva di
> qualsiasi significato malevolo**: nel rivedere un amico dopo tanti anni
> si potrebbe esclamare: Come stai? Che tte pòssin'ammazzàtte..., che
> suona come "Accidenti! Come stai?". In una forma ancora più mitigata,
> la seconda parte dell'espressione viene solo sottintesa: "te
> pòssino!..." o "che tte pòssino!...".

Come puoi leggere l’espressione *te possino* può quindi essere considerata un esclamazione molto usata nel linguaggio
comune, anche con funzione di duro o blando rimprovero.

Answer (score 1):

Inizialmente usata (nel Lazio principalmente) come minaccia (te possino ammazzatte, possano ammazzarti), “**te possino**” oggi è un’ espressione scherzosa (come molti altri “insulti” romani che oggi hanno una connotazione positiva), spesso utilizzata come rafforzativo, che significa “mannaggia a te”.

Ovviamente poi il significato dipende dal contesto, è ovvio che se stai litigando con qualcuno e ti dice “te possino ammazzatte” ti sta augurando la morte. Però di solito non ha questo significato: infatti, essendo io per metà del Lazio, quando vado, spesso mi sento dire “**Te possino** Federì, che sei bella/ che sei cresciuta/che sei brava” ovvero “Mannaggia a te Federica, quanto sei ”.

> “**Te possino**”  è quindi un’espressione Laziale (in uso anche in altre parti d’Italia con minore frequenza) usata come rafforzativo con connotazione positiva.

Su internet non ho trovato molto, [solo questo](http://www.turbozaura.it/tascabile.asp?idcategoria=Sub002):

> TE POSSINO AMMAZZATTE!: Apparentemente il significato sembrerebbe non lasciar dubbio sulle intenzioni di chi pronuncia il motto. In pratica l'espressione è usata raramente per intendere "che qualcuno ti uccida". Nella stragrande maggioranza dei casi è usato come rafforzativo finale di una frase; ad esempio, quando una madre chiama il proprio bambino che fa finta di non sentire, si esprime così: "viè qui, te possin'ammazzatte!". Anche in questo caso si ha una evidente dimostrazione della perdita del significato letterale dell'espressione: altrimenti una madre non si esprimerebbe in tal maniera nei confronti del proprio figliolo, sia pure per ottenere obbedienza. "Quanto acchitti, te possin'ammazzatte!" è un complimento con rafforzativo che vuol dire: come sei elegante! In un madrigale all'innamorata un improvvisato poeta si esprime così: - In poco tempo, quante me n'hai fatte! Fra fregature, buche e delusioni, m'hai rotto tutte quante l'illusioni, te possino e ripossin'ammazzatte!. L'ultimo verso ha soltanto il valore di un grosso rimprovero fatto in un momento d'ira all'innamorata che, come suol dirsi, si fa "tirare la calzetta"